# Difference between calling classmethod or regular method from another classmethod

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x

I have been lurking SO a long time and it happens that now it's my first time to ask a question since I couldn't find answer anywhere. I really hope that the title is not that confusing, I don't know how else to name it.

I am working on a Matrix class which I need for my college project (LUP decomposition, matrix inverse, solving linear equations...). Basic matrix operations, operator overloading, some helper methods, nothing too fancy.

As I was writing the code I came up with something that bothers me. I have a private method `_makeMatrix`. That method *creates* intended Matrix object. Then, I have classmethods like `createFromList` and `createFromFile` and similar, basically methods that allow a different way to create Matrix object. All of these methods call `_makeMatrix` to actually create Matrix object.

So, my question is, what is the difference between these two, except that in second case I can call `_makeMatrix` without creating object (which I obviously don't want to because `_makeMatrix` is intended to be private):

```
def _makeMatrix(r):
    # some code that creates Matrix object m
    return m

@classmethod
def createFromList(cls, matxList)
    # code that makes matxList suitable for passing to _makeMatrix()
    r = matxList
    return Matrix._makeMatrix(r)
```

and

```
@classmethod
def _makeMatrix(cls, r):
    # some code that creates Matrix object m
    return m

@classmethod
def createFromList(cls, matxList)
    # code that makes matxList suitable for passing to _makeMatrix()
    r = matxList
    return cls._makeMatrix(r)
```

What are the exact differences between these two and are there any benefits/drawbacks of using one or another approach?

Comment: On both codes you may write `c._makeMatrix(r)`. BTW, the correct name for this object per PEP-8 is `cls`

Comment: What is _makeMatrix in the first case? Instance or Static method? Instance Method would need self as 1st argument. Static method would need a decorator.

Comment: @JBernardo Thx, I didn't know PEP-8 defines that too.; @sureshvv Yes, you are right, I missed that, `self` should be there. I've edited my code to address that.

Comment: @dosvarog Now your code doesn't work... You will be missing an argument when you call `Matrix._makeMatrix(r)`

Comment: @JBernardo Yes, you are right. I was on mobile phone so I didn't have my code in front of me. My original code was without `self`, like your third example. I haven't realized that before, so what is going on here? Does Python implicitly treat that method as a static one, even though I didn't decorate it with `@staticmethod`? If I put `self` in `_makeMatrix` method, I have to call it with `cls._makeMatrix(cls, r)`, so I'm guessing there is also no difference between all these calls like in the previous examples? All this is a bit confusing, I have to admit.

Comment: @dosvarog When you access a method with the class, it will be treated as a pure function. So `def foo(self, bar)` is now a 2-argument function. It means that when you access `x.foo(10)` the interpreter is calling `MyClass.foo(x, 10)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper decorator for this example should be `staticmethod`. Here's why:

```
class MyClass:
    @classmethod
    def foo(cls, arg):
        # Here I can reference the class to work on things related to it
        # even if it is being accessed by an object of this class 
        pass


    @staticmethod
    def bar(arg):
        # This one behaves as a pure function unaware of the class it is
        # located on; even if it is accessed by an object of this class
        pass


    def baz(arg):
        # This one is tricky. Because it has no "self", it should crash
        # when accessed by an object of the class but not on the class
        # itself!
        pass
```

**Testing:**

```
x = MyClass()
x.foo(10) # OK, but `cls` is unused
x.bar(10) # OK!
x.baz(10) # Crash!!

MyClass.foo(10) # Ok, but `cls` is unused
MyClass.bar(10) # OK!
MyClass.baz(10) # OK!
```

So, whenever you need a "pure" function inside a class, i.e. a function which doesn't need any information from the class it is inserted this should be a `staticmethod`. If you don't want to instantiate an object but require some information from the class, you want `classmethod`.

Comment: Generally, I agree with you, but this doesn't quite answer my question. What I really want to know is, what is the difference between defining `_makeMatrix` as classmethod and calling it from `createFromList` like `cls._makeMatrix` or leaving it as instance (regular) method and calling it from `createFromList` like `Matrix._makeMatrix`? What is difference between these two calls? Is it just semantics or is Python internally doing something different?

Comment: @dosvarog There is no difference whatsoever because in this context `cls` **is**  `Matrix`. But it is always better to write `cls` (so your subclasses can work too)